# Adding product collection amount to title

Tags: php, magento, templates, e-commerce, categories

The base template for magento declares the product collection total in the toolbar (app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml) using the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
```

id like to add this to the end of the category title i.e. Category Name (18)
This also needs to be dynamic and change as per the filterable attributes.

The title resides on view.phtml (app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml)

If it makes a difference i am using 1.7.0.2 i also know you can use

```
<?php $_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection(); 
    $count = $_productCollection->getSize(); 
    echo $count;
?>
```

for the desired affect in app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit view.phtml and add this:

```
<h1>
   <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?> 
   <?php echo $this->getChild('product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection()->count()?>
</h1>
```

That's all.